# Reading large portions of files for hashing/checksums

Tags: php, hash, md5, fread

If I have three get parameters:

```
$filename = $_GET['filename'];
$start    = $_GET['start'];
$size     = $_GET['size'];
```

And I am reading a chunk of the file like so:

```
$handle   = fopen($basepath . $filename, "rb");
fseek($handle, $start);
$contents = fread($handle, $size);
echo md5($contents);
```

How may I read large portions of a file (anywhere from 1mb to 1gb) and create a hash or checksum of its contents without needing to allocate enough memory for the entire read?

At the moment if I try to hash a too large of part of the file I get a memory error since php can not allocated enough memory (roughly 400mb).

**Is there a hashing function in which I can digest parts of the file at a time rather than the entire contents at once (for example starting at `$start` read 100kb blocks and feed it to the function until `$size` is met)? And how would I read the file in chunks so that I would start at `$start` and read `$size` bytes?**

If there is not such a hashing or checksum function that supports feeding chunks of the data pieces at a time, **would `file_get_contents()` fix the issue of allocating memory for large reads?** I am not entirely sure how that function works.

Thanks.

Comment: whats the purpose of getting a hash for just part of a file?

Comment: It is part of a downloader script where the client side can download a http file in parts and ask for the hash/checksum of that portion of the file for comparison from the server side.

Comment: why not split server side with zip or tar

Comment: I don't want to pre-split the files or modify them in any way on the server side thus why I am using the range header to tell the httpd what segment of the file I am requesting to download. Unless I can get php to automate this splitting and feed the client script the correct part of the file then remove it directly afterwards although I really don't want new files being written to the file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-update.php

```
<?php
define('CHUNK', 65536);

//$file = 'alargefile.img';
//$start = 256 * 1024 * 1024;
//$size = 512 * 1024 * 1024;

$fp = fopen($file, "r");
fseek($fp, $start);
$ctx = hash_init('md5');
while ($size > 0) {
  $buffer = fread($fp, min($size, CHUNK));
  hash_update($ctx, $buffer);
  $size -= CHUNK;
}
$hash = hash_final($ctx);
fclose($fp);
print $hash;
?>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for although I believe there is a bug in how you read the file. Reducing the `$size` variable one by one yields the same hash multiple times in a row. Also setting `$start` to 0 and `$size` to the size of the file yields a wrong md5 hash as compared to `md5sum`. Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed it. The problem was `fgets` and presumably it stopping on newlines. Changing it to `fread` fixed the problem and it functions as it should. Thanks~